# I don't get out of the function Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple Angular code to show and hide a poppin, but every time I use it I am blocked in the function.

In my controller I have this to show the poppin :

```
    $scope.showHidden = function() {
        console.log('in')
        $scope.showIt = true;
    };
```

And this to hide it :

```
    $scope.hideIt = function() {
        console.log('out')
        $scope.showIt = false;
    };
```

And in my HTML :

```
    <li class="beer_list_item beer_item" ng-repeat="beer in beers | filter : myFilter" ng-click="showHidden()">
        <img ng-src="{{beer.img}} " alt="{{beer.alt}}" />
        <div class="beer_list_item_desc" ng-show="showIt">
            <h2 class="title1">{{beer.name}}</h2>
            <img src="{{beer.img}}" alt="{{beer.alt}}"/>
            <p>{{beer.desc}}</p>
            <button class="btn" ng-click="hideIt()">Close</button>
        </div>
    </li>
```

If I click on the item the poppin appears, and when I click on the close btn, I see 'out' and 'in' in my logs, and the poppin never disappear.

I'm sure it's a stupid mistake, but I don't see it. If anyone have an idea.. thanks by advance !

Comment: technically when you click on the close button, you are clicking on both the button and li elements, that's why you see both functions got called in the console.

Comment: Yes I just trying to put the first ng-click on the img and it works ... I knew it was stupid

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the `event propagation` when click on `hideIt`:

`<button class="btn" ng-click="hideIt();$event.stopPropagation();">Close</button>`

This could be a refactoring:

```js
function BeersCtrl($scope, beers) {
  $scope.beers = beers;
 
  $scope.showBeerList = true;
  
  $scope.toggleBeerList = function(event) {
    $scope.showBeerList = !$scope.showBeerList;  
  };
}


angular
  .module('test', [])
  .controller('BeersCtrl', BeersCtrl)
  .value('beers', [
    { name: 'Peroni' },
    { name: 'Guinnes' }
  ])
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="test">
  <article ng-controller="BeersCtrl">
    
    <div>
      <button 
              ng-click="toggleBeerList($event)"
              type="button">Toggle Beer List</beer> 
    </div>
    
    <ul ng-show="showBeerList">
      <li 
          ng-repeat="beer in beers">
        
        <span ng-bind="beer.name"></span>
      </li>
      
    </ul>
    
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But I just put the first ngClick on the img and it works.